# Upgrade Fedora 33 to Fedora 34 failed due to insufficient /var space

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I was performing an upgrade from Fedora 33 to Fedora 34
Everything seemed to work, then I did the system upgrade reboot, and that seemed to work too until I got to the login where I got just a black screen.

Escaping to shell I saw in the logs errors about lack of disk space in /var and sure it was 100%

Foolishly I deleted /var/tmp/* and now I can't boot at all to 34 or 33; I just get the dreaded "Oh snap: something went wrong"

I think it still wants to complete the upgrade but it can't.

At this point I'd just like to know if there is something I can do to just let it boot to 33 again, or somehow force it to continue the upgrade or wipe out that upgrade so I can start over.

Comment: This also happened to me. I think you probably can still boot but you will need to change the runlevel to 3. Try this https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-change-boot-runlevel-with-grub2/

Answer (score 1):

**Opinion:** `dnf upgrade` bug.

- `/var` being short on space should have been handled in the testing upgrade phase.

In my case, I did a snapshot of the VM and was able to go back, but many don't have that option. I certainly will not have that option on my laptop.

First, I had to allocate what ended up as an extra 4G, and depending on how many packages you have you may need more. One problem is the normal cleanup operation isn't done until the very end of the upgrade. So even while you are verifying it is consuming space... very annoying.

On the 4th attempt I knew what I was in for, so while it was upgrading, I did a `mingetty` session via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and logged in as `root`, then monitored with a `df -h /var`. I also had `ssm` system-storage-manager loaded, so that I could increase `/var` space quickly ensuring I had space in my root volume group to add space if needed (`ssm resize -s +1g /dev/vgname/varvol` would add space to logical volume and filesystem).

Remember if you are using `xfs`, that you can't shrink `/var` back down.

As long as I was able to keep ahead of the space consumption, I was able to let it go.

But... Fair warning to those who try the FC 33 to 34 upgrade, `/var` space will be a big issue if you don't plan for it.

Comment: An add-on.   I'm probably not going very far on a limb to say, the amount of trouble to try to fix the upgrade given all the packages that didn't install properly will be prohibitive.   You may be better off just installing fresh from a DVD or image.